# Entity Framework и SqLite

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite, entity-framework

Подскажите пожалуйста как совместить Entity Framework и SqLite? Поставил SqLite в проект уже через Nuget. Создал модель через конструктор, но БД еще не создавал. Не знаю что там и где выбрать или написать. Столько всяких менюшек, глаза разбегаются, если можно приведите кто нибудь скрины или статью какую нибудь со скринами действий по порядку.

P.S. И еще мне важно чтобы программа сама создавала БД если не нашла ее рядом.

UPD. Я решил попробовать через code first делать. На самом деле так может быть даже удобнее. :D Я просто не пробовал. Там вроде через удобный конструктор диаграмкой... С другой стороны там создается куча лишних файлов, а тут всего один файл и все... И я тут начал смотреть что в конфиге. Возможно просто надо настроить там? Вот смотрите что сейчас (это я еще sqlite подключил):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit [url]http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468[/url] -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=ConsoleApplication2.Model1;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Но это все автоматически сгенерировалось. Т.е. для БД будет использоваться MS SQL. А как заменить чтобы SQLite был? Я поэкспериментировал, но че то все время ошибки, в общем не знаю как настроить.

UPD. Погуглил эту ошибку и кажется нашел решение:

```
<provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
```

Кажется так вернее. Ошибка пропала, но появилась другая при вызове SaveChanges: "SQL logic error or missing database no such table: MyEntities". Я подозреваю что тут все проще: тупо не создана БД и таблица. Только тогда возникает вопрос: как их создать то? Ну я понимаю там MS Sql, там есть Managenent Studio, а что есть для SQLite? И потом мне важно чтобы программа сама могла создать БД если не нашла ее!!!

UPD. Причем я нашел метод CreateIfNotExists, но он че то возвращает false... Хотя кстати файл БД создается в папке с программой, но он 0 байт, ну и плюс ошибка это по прежнему.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.EF6, судя по всему.

Comment: @VladD :рукалицо: написано же что я поставил SqLite в проект. Неужели вы думаете я не найду где скачать?

Comment: @DarkByte Если вы сами нашли где скачать SQLite - что же вам помешало там же найти как к базе подключиться?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov вам не приходило в голову что скачать проще чем подключиться?

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо заменить строку подключения к БД

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1" connectionString="Data Source=(путь к файлу);Version=3" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Важно, чтобы `providerName` был правильный - указывал на провайдера SQLite, а не MS SQL.

---

PS Небольшой совет по поводу оптимизации схемы БД - все ключи сущностей, которые были `int` - замените на `long`. SQLite быстрее назодит запись в таблице если ее первичный ключ - `long`.

Comment: "Для поставщика ADO.NET с неизменяемым именем "System.Data.SQLite" не найден поставщик Entity Framework. Убедитесь, что поставщик зарегистрирован в разделе "entityFramework" файла конфигурации приложения. Дополнительные сведения см. на странице http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882."

Comment: @DarkByte я вам как бы другое `providerName` написал

Comment: я полностью скопировал ваш код.